# Check if variable is set before adding key to array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using the Stripe API like so:

```
$coupon = $_POST["coupon"];

$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
  "customer" => $customer->id,
  "plan" => $plan,
  "coupon" => $coupon,
));
```

This works great when $coupon is set and it's a valid coupon code. If I leave it blank (i.e., customer didn't include a coupon code in form submitted), Stripe throws an error. If I include a coupon code that doesn't exist in Stripe, it throws an error.

So, the question is, how do I build this array to NOT have the `coupon` key when the variable `$coupon` is empty?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["coupon"]))` ?

Comment: Or `if (!empty())`

Comment: @Gogol I know how to check if the variable is set, but if it is not set, then I can't even include the `"coupon"` key in my array.

Comment: @u_mulder What am i checking? and what's the else?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['coupon']) && !empty($_POST['coupon']))`

Comment: What array? $_POST?

Comment: @JigarShah `isset` is completely redundant there.

Comment: @Don'tPanic How would you do it?

Comment: @jonmrich Like u_mulder's answer.

Comment: @Don'tPanic   but it will check for empty as well?

Comment: @JigarShah empty checks isset before checking if the value evaluates to true.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :) .

Comment: @jonmrich for an answer with an elegant syntax https://stackoverflow.com/a/45108226/3663471 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$payment_data = array(
  "customer" => $customer->id,
  "plan" => $plan,
);
if (!empty($_POST['coupon'])) {
    $payment_data["coupon"] = $_POST['coupon'];
}

$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create($payment_data);
```

Comment: will throw exception if `$_POST["coupon"]` not set.

Comment: __Nope__, will __not__ throw neither exception nor warning  if `$_POST['coupon']` is not set.

Comment: Reading is not your strong part)

Comment: Was glad to help)

Comment: @Gogol From the PHP documentation for empty: _"A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist."_

Answer (score 3):

I would write it like that:

```
$args = [
  'customer' => $customer->id,
  'plan' => $plan,
];
if (!empty($_POST['coupon'])) {
  $args['coupon'] = $_POST['coupon'];
}
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create($args);
```

But it depends. Thanks to Don't Panic for pointing out that `empty` is the better choice and not `isset`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it you can use if conditions and restructure your code. But I believe this would be a beautiful code if you can use the shorthand if clauses.

```
($coupon) ? $arr['coupon'] = $coupon : '';
```

This reads if you've got the variable `$coupon` set, then assign it to the array `$arr` with the key `'coupon'`, else do nothing.

Your full code segment would look like,

```
$coupon = $_POST["coupon"];

$arr = array(
 "customer" => $customer->id,
 "plan" => $plan
);

// Magic happens here
($coupon) ? $arr['coupon'] = $coupon : '';

$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create($arr);
```